# Memory Leak Detecting and overriding new?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, unmanaged

I am attempting to get Memory leak detection working with the help of these two articles:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28VS.80%29.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q140858/

So in my stdafx.h I now have:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#define new new(_NORMAL_BLOCK,__FILE__,__LINE__)
```

The only problem is, I have a class which overrides the new function:

```
class Dummy
{    
  //overloaded new operator
  void FAR* operator new(size_t cb);
}
```

Now when I compile this code, I get:
error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
error C2091: function returns function

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: That's the problem with macros :(

Comment: If you weren't using windows, I'd suggest valgrind.

Comment: I'd use DUMA if I were using Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You  can use pragma directives to save and restore the new macro when undefing for overloads. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsttss76(VS.71).aspx) for the exact syntax.

E.g.

```
#pragma push_macro("new")
#undef new
void FAR* operator new(size_t cb);
#pragma pop_macro("new")
```

You can put these in headers, e.g.

begin_new_override.h:

```
#ifdef new
#define NEW_WAS_DEFINED
#pragma push_macro("new")
#undef new
#endif
```

end_new_override.h:

```
#ifdef NEW_WAS_DEFINED
#undef NEW_WAS_DEFINED
#pragma pop_macro("new")
#endif
```

And then

```
#include "begin_new_override.h"
void FAR* operator new(size_t cb);
#include "end_new_override.h"
```

Comment: Cool, I had no idea this was possible :-)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of defining new to be something different, why not overload operator new?

Add these function definitions somewhere in the global namespace:

```
// operator new overloads
void* operator new( const size_t size, const char* file, int line) throw();
void* operator new( const size_t size, const size_t align, const char* file, int line) throw();
void* operator new[]( const size_t size, const char* file, int line) throw();
void* operator new[]( const size_t size, const size_t align, const char* file, int line) throw();

// can't easily overload operator delete
void operator delete( void* ptr ) throw();
void operator delete[]( void* ptr ) throw();

// matched to the operator new overload above in case of exceptions thrown during allocation
void operator delete( void* ptr, const char* file, int line) throw();
void operator delete[]( void* ptr, const char* file, int line) throw();
void operator delete( void* ptr, const size_t align, const char* file, int line) throw();
void operator delete[]( void* ptr, const size_t align, const char* file, int line) throw();

// global new/delete
void* operator new( size_t size ) throw();
void* operator new( size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& ) throw();
void* operator new( size_t size, size_t align ) throw();
void* operator new( size_t size, size_t align, const std::nothrow_t& ) throw();

void* operator new[]( size_t size ) throw();
void* operator new[]( size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& ) throw();

void operator delete( void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) throw();
void operator delete[]( void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) throw();
```

Then you can define your own new macro which calls through to the non-global versions and implement the global versions to assert or warn if they're called (to catch anything slipping through).

```
#define MY_NEW(s)    new(s, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Your class-level overloads will work as expected if you call 'new' directly on the class. If you want to call MY_NEW on the class, you can but you'll have to redefine the overload in the class to match your new.

Comment: `__LINE__` is an `int`, not a `char*`.

Comment: Helped me understanding the specific overloads for the new and delete operators.

Answer (score 4):

Redefining `new` via `#define` at the preprocessor level is a bad idea in my experience -- you not only break `operator new` overloads, but also placement `new`, and probably a few other things.

Having all those FILE and LINE macros expanding everywhere causes your .rodata and .data sections to bloat with file strings and line numbers, and generates much more code per call.

Much better (if more effort up-front) to take advantage of the existence of debug information (e.g. `.pdb` file) and use something like the `DbgHelp` library's [StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650(VS.85).aspx) to gather stack info.

Overload the various combinations of global operator new and operator delete (array, nothrow, etc), have them store and release stack information as memory is allocated and freed.

You can even store this information in a structure like a std::map<void *, StackInfo>, just be careful to not record the allocs caused by the map inserts (a global lock may be sufficient for a single-threaded app, multi-threaded is left as an exercise to the reader).

Since you're recording the entire stack for any given alloc, you can do some nifty tree analysis, grouping allocations (leaks or otherwise) by "function and descendants"...  And it is sometimes easier to trace complicated leaks if you know the entire stack from their allocation time.

Comment: Incidentally, if someone already knows of a library/toolkit to do this sort of thing (store alloc info with stack traces) under windows -- barring commercial solutions -- I'd love to hear about it, and will happily update the answer.  No reason to reinvent the wheel.  The version of this I used was on an embedded platform...

Comment: Try looking into ETW traces with windows. The tools are free and small so can be dropped on clients machines to help with debugging. Also you can post extra information into the etw traces yourself from your application. they can track memory allocations and deallocations and capture stack information for each one. The hardest thing about it is that setting up WPA to show the information you want can be daunting.

There are some useful videos linked here to get you started:

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/etw-training-videos-available-now/

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`#undef new`
before class definition
and then `#define new new...` again after.